# Native Win32 NLS - strange default sub language for Portuguese

Tags: winapi, localization, internationalization, locale

Doing LANGID and LCID gymnastics right now. Just noticed that in native Win32 NLS, SUBLANG_PORTUGUESE_BRAZILIAN is the user default sub language for the LANG_PORTUGUESE primary language. I expected SUBLANG_PORTUGUESE to be the default sub language. Why isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose it has something to do with sheer user base. I mean much more people live in Brazil than in Portugal. So it is probably better default value.

Comment: I really didn't think about that option. Thanks!